# Are derivatives with complex powers possible?

Tags: calculus

I was thinking about the derivatives of functions

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f^\prime(x)$$

and how if $f(x)$ was infinitely differentiable like if $f(x)=e^x$, one could then have

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)=f^{n}(x)$$

where n is any real number (since there are such things as fractional powers of derivatives). Is it possible to have an $n$ such that it is a complex number?

I have searched google but there doesn't seem to have anything on the 'complex powers of derivatives'. Also I don't know what tags I should use for this so I will simply put 'calculus'.

Comment: It is entirely possible that there is a working definition that I am not aware of -- but note that complex numbers cannot be ordered like reals.

Comment: I have never even heard of non-whole number powers of derivatives.  How do you define $\dfrac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}}}$?  Or $\dfrac{d^{\pi}}{dx^{\pi}}$?

Comment: This will be of interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: I feel like putting a bounty if I only had enough credits...

Comment: Horus - read levap's link, which specifically mentions complex exponents on the derivative operator.

Comment: @PaulSinclair ...indeed it does. Thanks for the heads up.